# Wordpress. Код добавленный в header.php не работает, в чем может быть причина?

Tags: php, wordpress, header

Добавил код google tag manager в header.php, но его по факту нет в коде сайта. Вот [сайт](https://rozpys-stin.rv.ua/)
А вот код который, я вставил в header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Chronus
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-M8QDRH5');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-M8QDRH5"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<?php do_action( 'wp_body_open' ); ?>

    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'chronus' ); ?></a>

    <?php do_action( 'chronus_header_bar' ); ?>

    <?php chronus_header_image(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'chronus_before_site' ); ?>

    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">

        <?php do_action( 'chronus_before_header' ); ?>

        <header id="masthead" class="site-header clearfix" role="banner">

            <div class="header-main container clearfix">

                <div id="logo" class="site-branding clearfix">

                    <?php chronus_site_logo(); ?>
                    <?php chronus_site_title(); ?>
                    <?php chronus_site_description(); ?>

                </div><!-- .site-branding -->

            </div><!-- .header-main -->

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/navigation', 'main' ); ?>

        </header><!-- #masthead -->

        <?php do_action( 'chronus_after_header' ); ?>

        <?php chronus_featured_content(); ?>

        <?php chronus_breadcrumbs(); ?>

        <div id="content" class="site-content container clearfix">
```

Comment: Код должен быть в теле вопроса, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
Добавил код google tag manager в header.php, но его по факту нет в коде сайта.
```

Удали это, восстанови оригинальный файл.
А код добавляй при помощи плагинов. [Выбирай понравившийся](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/code+header/). Или [так](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/tag+manager/)